# Querydsl selecting from a subquery runtime exception

Tags: sql, querydsl

I'm stuck on how to select from a subquery using Querydsl on SQL. The code compiles fine, but I'm getting a runtime exception: `Undeclared path 'cases'. Add this path as a source to the query to be able to reference it.`

The code looks approximately like this:

```
private ListSubQuery<Integer> getStudyCaseSubQuery(CaseQuery query) {
    SQLSubQuery sq = new SQLSubQuery().from(cases);
    ... stuff happens
    return sq.list(cases.id);
}

...

public List<JsonObject> getData(...) {
    // Build a common subquery for a bunch of other queries
    ListSubQuery<Integer> caseQuery = getStudyCaseSubQuery(...);

    // This fails with runtime exception
    List<Integer> caseIds = caseQuery.list(Expressions.path(Integer.class, cases, "id"));
}
```

I can see where the problem is: I can't find a way to specify an alias for the subquery apart from a whole table, which isn't the case here. There's a bunch of examples that use `Alias` and `Path` but nothing that matches in the tests or tutorials that I can adapt to this problem. Although I know SQL pretty well, aliasing tables and columns appear entirely different in Querydsl, but the examples I've found don't really elaborate on the differences, so clarification would be extremely helpful.

Comment: Well, I can't edit the question, sadly. And it's wrong. The error was the same method but in an earlier attempt to use the subquery. However, I'm still keen for clarification, because the subquery only returns an `id` field, and yet it's being aliased the same as the original table. I'd like to be able to alias to a non-table name. I'll edit the question to fix if SO ever lets me.

Comment: I can't understand the code structure good enough from your example code, could you provide an SQL query as an example?